# Is an HTML page created as a table with rows and columns which are invisible?

Tags: html

when i print 3 buttons they are in a single line, but is i print 10, some are shown in a new line? How does this happen. I didnt use a CSS.

````
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>
<p></p>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>```
````

Answer (score 1):

> Is an HTML page created as a table with rows and columns which are invisible?

No.

Not unless there is an explicit table element.

---

> when i print 3 buttons they are in a single line, but is i print 10, some are shown in a new line? How does this happen.

By default, when multiple things are side by side, they wrap when they get to the end of the line.

It would be very hard to use most webpages if you had to scroll left and right all the time because of a lack of explicit line breaks suited for the window width you are using.

Answer (score -2):

The HTML table model allows authors to arrange data -- text, preformatted text, images, links, forms, form fields, other tables, etc. -- into rows and columns of cells.
[enter link description here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html)

Comment: While this is true it (a) has nothing to do with the question that was asked and (b) that link points to an obsolete specification